# How can I use MagickNet from C# to stitch images together?

Tags: c#, .net, image, imagemagick, magicknet

I want to stitch some images together using MagickNet (jpg/bmp - whatever).

Does anyone have some good references for this?

Comment: Or FreeImage.NET http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

From the sourceforge project forum at FreeImage.NET:

Hi,

use FreeImage_Allocate to create a new, empty (black) result image. Load each of your images to be stitched with FreeImage_Load. Use FreeImage_Paste for to paste the loaded image into the result image, where parameter dst is your allocated result image and parameter src is the loaded image. After pasting the image, unload the image with FreeImage_Unload to prevent your app from leaking memory. After having pasted all images, save your result image with FreeImage_Save. Then also free the result image's memory by unloading it with another call to FreeImage_Unload.

Attention: Currently, the image pasted with FreeImage_Paste must not exceed any of the destination image's sides. There is no automatic clipping performed so, you have to ensure that parameters top and left are not smaller than 0 (zero) and left +  as well as top +  are not greater than the width or height of the destination image respectively.

Carsten